# foor loop doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is my lift programm:

```js
var person = {
  name: "Roman",
  position: 7,
  goal: 9
};

var lift = {
  getPosition: function() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    return x;
  }()
};

console.log("Ok " + person.name + "! You are at " + person.position + " floor");
console.log("Lift is at " + lift.getPosition + " floor");

if (lift.getPosition > person.position) {
  for (i = lift.getPosition; i >= person.position; i--) {
    console.log(i);
  }
} else if (lift.getPosition < person.position) {
  for (i = lift.getPosition; i <= person.Position; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
console.log("Please enter inside!");
```

For loop about raising lift doesn't work. Lift falling but not raising. What's the wrong?

Comment: Your if else is missing the equals condition.

Comment: Is the function inside the lift object being called and returning a value?

Answer (score 2):

You've capitalized `Position` in your second for loop.

Should be

```
for (i = lift.getPosition; i <= person.position; i++) {
```

(with a lowercase `p` in `person.position`)

Since there is no `Position` property in the `lift` object, the for loop condition is basically asking if `i <= undefined`.  This will always evaluate to false and therefore your loop never iterates.

Comment: `getPosition` is not a function. The function is called immediately and a number is assigned. But whether that's intentional or not I can't say.

Comment: Oops.  I'm an idiot.  Thanks for pointing that out @FelixKling.  Taking a second look...

Comment: You might want to explain why that causes the loop not to run.

Comment: Thanks again @FelixKling.  Explanation provided.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, not wrapping an IIFE in parenthesis. Gets me every time too…

Answer (score 0):

person.**p**osition != person.**P**osition

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a case sensitive language, you should care about upper and lower case. your `person` object contains `position` but not `Position` that is why it is not working. Just change the `Position` to `position` in the second for loop.

your second loop should look like the following loop.

```
for (i = lift.getPosition; i <= person.position; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
```